# libgdx getChildByName xml files, how to test if a element exit

Tags: xml, libgdx

how to test if a Child element on xml file exit using libgdx ?

I have this for read

```
Element filtroXml = cenaXML.getChildByName("filtro");
ObjetoJogo.filtro = filtroXml.getText();
```

I need to test if "filtro" element exite and if yes than read

Comment: not exit, but exist

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of *getChildByName(String name)* `@return the first child having the given name or null, does not recurse`
So if element exists it will return it, if it does not exist it will return null.

You can do like this:

```
XmlReader.Element book = element.getChildByName("book");
if(book != null) {
    //Book exists, I can operate on it
    String content = book.getText();
}
else {
    //Book doesn't exist
    Gdx.app.debug("XML","Book does not exist!");
}
```